# rich-table-subheadercell affect all the subheader

Tags: jsf, datatable, richfaces

I'm using richfaces to create a datatable. the table has two headers, I want to color the background of one cell of the second header, I found the class rich-table-subheadercell, wihen I use it for one column it color all the second header.

```
<rich:dataTable  rowClasses="greyRow, whiteRow" id="table" rendered=" " 
                    headerClass="class1"
                    columnClasses="redColumn"
                    onRowMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='#{cardsWebPortalBean.selected_color}'"
                    onRowMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#{org.richfaces.SKIN.tableBackgroundColor}'"
                    width="1120px" rows="5" 
                    value=""
                    var="" rowKeyVar="row">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <rich:columnGroup>
            <rich:column width="15">
                <h:outputText value="#{msgMS.lbl_Hist}" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column >
                <h:outputText value="" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column width="95">
                <h:outputText value="" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column width="50">
                <h:outputText value="#" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column width="130">
                <h:outputText value="#" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column width="85">
                <h:outputText value="#" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column width="70">
                <h:outputText value="#" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column width="70" >
                <h:outputText value="#" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column width="25"  >
                <h:outputText value="#" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column width="15" styleClass="rich-table-subheadercell">
            <h:outputText value="#{msgMS.lbl_Serv}" />
    </rich:column>
</rich:columnGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by specifing the number of cell, like in simple table:

```
.rich-table-subheadercell:nth-child(10){
         background-color: #db8888 !important;
        background-image:none !important;
}
```